# On scene Three js displays a different color at LineBasicMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created the outline of the box with LineBasicMaterial.

`new LineBasicMaterial({ color: '#ff1b00', linewidth: 1 }`

But in scene the color has a different shade, when i use color picker - color is #db5100. Why? And how to fix it?

Set up webGlRender:

```
this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true, powerPreference: 'high-performance', precision: 'highp' })
this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
this.renderer.gammaOutput = true;
this.renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping
this.renderer.toneMappingExposure = 0.7;
this.renderer.gammaFactor = 2.2
this.renderer.gammaOutput = true;
this.renderer.powerPreference = 'high-performance'
this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = false;
this.renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // default THREE.PCFShadowMap
this.dom.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)
```

Comment: Let's see the code where you set up your WebGLRenderer? I'm thinking it might have something to do with `gammaOutput`, `outputEncoding`, or `toneMapping`.

Comment: @Marquizzo hi! Thx for your answer. I supplemented the question with what you asked.